# What's the difference between include, require and open in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

For example,

include: `include Ppx_core`

open: `open Core.Std`

require: `#require "compiler-libs.common"`

and use: `#use "topfind"`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `include` [re-exports](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/modules.html#sec210) the components of the module in the current structure: the module you are in will contain all definitions that are in `Ppx_core`.
- `open` makes the components of the module [directly accessible](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/modules.html#sec209) in the typing environment. Instead of typing `Core.Std.element` you can just type `element`.
- `#require` is a [Topfind](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.7.1/doc/ref-html/lib/Topfind.html) command that finds a library and loads it, making its modules accessible to you.
- `#use` behave as if [copying a full file](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html#sec275) directly into your toplevel.

Note that the `#`-keywords are not part of the OCaml language but are toplevel commands: they won't work if you try to compile your file.

Comment: perhaps a hands-on example for each would be nice and make the answer self-contained?

Answer (score 8):

The `include Module.Name` statement in the module definition will include all definitions from a module named `Module.Name`. The definitions will be included roughly as they were copy-pasted. If the `include Module.Name` occurs inside of the module type definition (aka signature definition), the the `Module.Name` should be a valid (known to a compiler) module type. It will include the definition of a module type as it is (without including any type sharing constraints).

The `open Module.Name` statement occurring in both module implementation and module signature, will allow you to refer to definitions (values, types, submodules) of a `Module.Name` without using a fully qualified named, i.e., using short names without the `Module.Name` prefix.

The `#require` statement is not a statement at all and is not a part of OCaml grammar. It is special directive of the OCaml toplevel - the interactive loop. The same as ipython has its own directives. The `require` directive will load the specified package, and all its dependencies. Moreover, this directive is not a part of a standard OCaml toplevel distribution, but is added by the `topfind` script that is a part of the ocamlfind toolkit. The `#use` directive is used to load and evaluate a script. For example `#use "topfind"` will load and evaluate the `topfind` script from the OCaml standard library folder. This script will register the `require` directive. There are also `#load` and `#load_rec` directives, that work on a more fine-granular level, rather than packages -- these directives are intendend to load libraries.